# Catel ModelBase<T> error

Tags: entity-framework, catel

I'm trying to use ModelBase as the base class for EntityBase as suggested in the documentation at https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+ModelBase+as+base+for+entities.

I'm using VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop (C#), EF v6 and Catel v3.9.

When trying to build the app I receive the following error message:

> Error  1 `Catel.Data.ModelBase<T>` is obsolete: Generic class is no longer being used, use the non-generic base instead Please use `ModelBase` instead. Will be removed in version 4.0.0.

I'm unfamiliar with Catel and Entity Framework so would appreciate up-to-date guidance on how I should be using these together.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is very clear:

"Catel.Data.ModelBase is obsolete" means that it will be removed from Catel in future usages and thus must no longer be used.

Luckily the message also says something else:

"use the non-generic base instead Please use ModelBase instead" which means that you can use the **ModelBase** class instead of **ModelBase**.

I have also updated the documentation page to use ModelBase instead of ModelBase.